# Rendering .tif in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, rendering, arcgis-10.7

I'm working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 ModelBuilder and was wondering if there is a way to automatically export the TIFFs my model creates into a rendered TIFF.

Below is a photo of what I'm trying to recreate.

[image]

Is there a code in arcpy that I can use to recreate this export function?

Comment: I'm not aware of any geo-processing tool that honours the `Use Renderer` parameter that can be found in the Export Raster Dialog. If you wanted to simply make a copy of the source raster then Copy Raster tool could used in model builder?

Comment: I've tried using it in model builder, however copy raster doesn't create the exact same product as export raster.